# CSS textbox width inherit from parent container with max width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the styling for my textboxes:

```
input[type=text] {
   width: 300px !important;
   line-height: 25px;
}
```

I need to change it that if the container width is smaller than 300px it must inherit the width from the parent container else the width must be 300px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input {
   max-width: 300px;
   width:100%;
   line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This does what was asked for, but it means that the rendered width of the `input` element is slightly larger than that of the container. The reason is that an `input` element has a default border and padding. To make the rendered width the same as the container width, add `input { box-sizing: border-box }`.